# Is there proof show that $\log x$ is undefined and make no sense at $ x=0$?

Tags: logarithms, definition, exponential-function

I was asked by someone: why $\log x$ is undefined at $x=0 $?

Is there proof  show that $\log x$ is undefined at $x=0$?

Note(01):: log is the inverse function of the exponential function.

note(02): I edited my question as I meant why it's not make a sens at $x=0$ ?

Thank you for your help .

Comment: No, it's an **inverse function**, not a **reciprocal**.

Comment: but what about it's graph before we know it ?

Comment: and what about algebra arguments ?

Comment: Check out the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Definitions) of logarithm and see why you cannot plugin $x=0$.

Comment: Because $e^x\ne0$ for every $x$ (and in turn, this holds because $e^xe^{-x}=e^{x+(-x)}=e^0=1\ne0$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could define $\log0$ in whatever way we like, but a sensible definition should preserve the main property of the logarithm, that is,
$$
\log(xy)=\log x+\log y
$$
Suppose we set $\log0=a$; then, taking $y=0$ in the formula above, we have
$$
\log(x0)=\log x+\log0
$$
that is,
$$
a=\log x+a
$$
and we conclude that $\log x=0$. But $x$ can be any positive number! So defining the logarithm at $0$ to be some real number, forces $\log x=0$ for any other $x>0$.

Not really a useful function, I believe you can agree, and certainly not the inverse to the exponential function.

Comment: how : log(0.0)=log0+log0 ??

Comment: @zeraouliarafik *If* we want to preserve the property, we *must* have it. The conclusion is that we can't define $\log0$ *and* preserve the property. What do we give up to?

Comment: I'm not sure this works.  If you look at the standard proof of the multiplicative property of logarithms, there is an implicit assumption that $x,y \neq 0$.  So using the property is assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: @Paul That's *exactly* what I do: *suppose* it's possible to define $\log0$ so that $\log(xy)=\log x+\log y$ holds for $x,y\ge0$; then $\log x=0$, for all $x\ge0$. Which is obviously contradictory. Hence it is not possible to extend log at $0$ so the property still holds. I started with *a sensible definition should preserve the main property of the logarithm*.

Comment: @egreg, that "main property of the logarithm" is not an axiom of the logarithm; it is a derived property to the logarithm.  And that derivation assumes that the argument is not equal to zero.

Comment: @Paul So what? Real numbers are an extension of the rational numbers, where all field axioms are still valid. Mathematics is full of such things; in this case it's not possible to define $\log0$ so that the properties are preserved. That's all. The OP asked for justifications of the fact that the logarithm is undefined at $0$; saying it's defined for $x>0$ is not an answer to *this* question.

Comment: @egreg One can define $log(0)$ as $-\infty $. Your formula then becomes: $- \infty = log(x) - \infty$. This is in agreement with the rules of addition when dealing with infinity. I don't see a violation of the main property of the logarithm.

Comment: @M.Wind The problem with adding $-\infty$ is that we can't preserve all laws of arithmetic. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

Since the logarithm is *defined* as the inverse function of the exponential function, the *domain* of $\log x$ is exactly the *range* of $e^x$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined" means not defined. We have simply not defined what what $\log(0)$ means. There is no proof for this.

You CAN show why it would not make sense to define $\log(0)$, but this is NOT a proof that $\log(0)$ is not defined.

As for a "visual proof", just look at the graph of $\log(x)$ and note that we want to $\log(x)$ to be continuous.

Comment: ok, sorry for my question , i meant a proof why it's not make a sense at x=0, pleas i want to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Visual demonstration: As avid19 stated, look at the graph of $\log x$.  It is negative for $0 < x < 1$, and as $x$ gets closer and closer to zero, it clearly goes below any value that you might define $\log 0$ to be.

Algebraic demonstration: $y = \log x$ means $x = e^y$.  (Assuming $\log x$ is natural log, but it really doesn't matter that much.)  Whatever value of $y$ you might choose for $L \equiv \log 0$, notice that you can find an $x < e^y$ such that $\log x \ll L$.  Thus it doesn't make sense to define $\log 0$.

This is just the examination of the graph of $\log x$, put into words.

Answer (score 0):

The natural logarithm is defined as

$$
\log x = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} \, dt
$$

Naively plugging in $0$, we get

$$
\log 0 = \int_{1}^{0} \frac{1}{t} \, dt = - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t} \, dt,
$$

However, the area under $y = 1 / t$ from $0$ to $1$ diverges to $\infty$, which would imply

$$
\log 0 = - \infty
$$

Intuitively, that's why $\log 0$ is undefined, which is inline with your original question.

Answer (score 0):

For the exponential function we all agree that $exp(- \infty) = 0$. Now the logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function. Applying it to both sides we obtain: $log(0) = - \infty$. This is perfectly sound, but mathematicians prefer to exclude the point $x = 0$ from the domain. That is all, really.